# How to call ant from perl script that is called from Hudson

Tags: hudson

Hudson allows us to specify the ant version that we want to use. Now, what I want to do is having Hudson call my perl script which then will call ant. how do I do this?

When I tried to call ant from perl script that was called from Hudson, I got the following error:

```
Can't exec "ant": No such file or directory at ...........
```

I understand that this error means "ant" is not in the path. The thing is that if I provide the exact location or add ant to the path, then that means I am not using ant that I specified from Hudson.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't actually want to invoke ant as a Hudson build step which will happen if you add it as a build step. How about making it a parameterized Choice as ANT_VERSION with options: /opt/apache-ant-1.8.0, /opt/apache-ant-x.y.z, etc. Then in your Execute Shell build step do:

```
my-perl-script.pl --ant-version=${ANT_VERSION}
```

where your script takes the path to the ant version as a paramter.